React Query cant render data using map() function
I fetched data from server in my demo app with React Query useQuery() hook. I have data(type of array which hold elements with type="game" or type="individualTraining") present inside component but I can't use map() function to render it conditionally on the screen. Do you see what is problem?
function Calendar(props) {
  const id = 3;
  const { data, isPending, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["calendar"],
    queryFn: () => {
      return fetchUpcomingGames(id);
    },
  });

  let content;

  if (isPending) {
    content = "Loading...";
  }
  if (isError) {
    content = "Error occurred: " + error.message;
  }
  if (data) {
    content = (
      <div className={`${classes.gameAndIndTraContainer}`}>
        {data.map((element) => {
          element.type === "game" ? <h1>Game</h1> : <h1>IndividualTraining</h1>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <>{content}</>;
}

export default Calendar;

`
I tried to convert data to array with Object.values(data) and it also shows nothing on the screen

So what is the error you're seeing in the console?

there is no error, when I render "data[0].type" it shows "game" on the screen and also all other fields of element of that given array, but when using map() function there is nothing rendered

Add console.log(data) after if (data) to see what content you're dealing with.

it gives me a array of 2 objects, and "Source map error: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Resource URL: null
Source Map URL: react_devtools_backend_compact.js.map"

Well that's probably your isssue, invalid JSON

I put both object types of array into JSON validator. It says that JSON is valid.
This is how I combine array of 2 objects (game and individualTraining):

fetch them from backend one by one
in for loops give them additional attribute - dateTime, so they can be sorted
combine games and individual trainings into one array and sort them by dateTime
return that array and render it on the screen

